# Windows EC2 userdata powershell script run as administrator

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, ec2-userdata

Need help to run a powershell userdata script as administrator during the start up of instance.

sample code i used is

```
<powershell>
net.exe session 1>NUL 2>NUL || (powershell "Start-Process -FilePath Cmd.exe -ArgumentList \"/c %~dpnx0\" -Verb RunAs" & goto :eof)
cd c:/
Write-Output "creating required directories"
mkdir test
mkdir logs

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME', 'C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-8', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('LOG_APPENDER', 'json', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

I added  and 
I was hoping this will help to run script as administrator `net.exe session 1>NUL 2>NUL || (powershell "Start-Process -FilePath Cmd.exe -ArgumentList \"/c %~dpnx0\" -Verb RunAs" & goto :eof)` but the script is not running.
i need to run as administrator coz i have few environment variables to be set as system variables.

Can you please suggest what is missing

Comment: What makes you say "but the script is not running." ?

Comment: I was able to see the environment variables are not set